Queries on Hive + Iceberg + S3 usecase
I'm relatively new to Apache Hive. I'm looking to set up a standalone Apache Hive metastore for a particular use case (described below), and my questions are related to this use case.

Use case: I'm trying to set up a standalone Hive metastore to be used solely as an Iceberg catalog for storing data in Amazon S3 (the metadata for the metastore itself could be on Postgres).

Questions:

Do I really need to configure S3 details in metastore-site.xml (like metastore.warehouse.dir) and core-site.xml (like fs.defaultFS and fs.s3a.*)?
What are the AuthN and AuthZ options for the standalone metastore available for me (if any)?

I tried removing core-site.xml and parts of metastore-site.xml that contains references to s3a. I was expecting CRUD operations on the S3 storage (via the metastore) to work. But I could see logs in the metastore attempting connections to S3 and failing.
